# how to connect points to create a polygon boundary in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, geometry-conversion

I have 31 points in a shapefile, which delimit a field (it's an irregular shape). I want to connect those points so they create the boundary of a polygon. Does anybody know a kind of "connect the dots" tool?

Comment: This is not available in 2.2……

Answer (score 3):

The plugin you are looking for is called Points2One. (You might have to allow experimental plugins to install it.)

Comment: If this doesnt work you could try the convex hull tool.

Comment: The convex hull tool solves a different problem though. It's not a replacement.