# Merge two points of two different polygons to get one polygon at the end

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, features, merge

I would like to **join points** **from** two **different features**. I already searched for plugins, but so far but didn't find one working plugin or solution for my task.

So here is a picture of 2 polygons/feautures:
[image]

I already marked 2 points and these shall be merged with the other both on the left side. So at the end I would like to have one polygon and the 4 points in the middle for sure shall be 2.

*Similar questions:*

- [Join attributes of point and line layer by location (closest distance) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/join-attributes-of-point-and-line-layer-by-location-closest-distance-in-qgis)
- [how to connect points to create a polygon boundary in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52354/how-to-connect-points-to-create-a-polygon-boundary-in-qgis)
- [How to merge lines with slightly different endpoints in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/how-to-merge-lines-with-slightly-different-endpoints-in-qgis)

Comment: How should the end result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Enable vertex *snapping* on the feature
2) Use the **Node Tool** and drag the vertexes from the right polygon to the one on the left (the snapping will allow you to place them exactly on top of each other)
3) From the **Advanced Digitizing** tools use the **Merge Selected Features** tool (note that you have to select both features first!)

**EDIT**:
Screenshots of the tools:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I must admit that way was already known to me and worked in some cases. But the snapping is kind of buggy so far I have found out. Sometimes, working, but often it does not snap correctly (even with high snapping amount pixels). I did several tests on that. So maybe there is real way to join 2 points? But anyway your way works overall, thanks. Just not directly what I'm looking for =)

Comment: It might depend on your snapping tolerance, have you played around with that?

Comment: Sure yes. And one time it only worked from feature 1. to 2. but not the other way around. Something is very buggy there. So it would be much better to go a direct way of merging 2 points instead of this workaround. I hope you got my point. Anyway your solution works, but currently too buggy in QGIS for me =/

Comment: Hm, strange, it always worked for me. But I also noticed that when datasets get very large, QGIS tends to slow down, and sometimes that messes up the editing. Do you have the issue with different datasets or just one specific one? Sometimes it might just be the dataset too.

Comment: Well when I tested with small sets it seemed to always work, but I didn't hardcore tested that. Because you know at the end it needs to work on real data =). Maybe that's the main issue indeed. But a polygon with 4k points is not so super special I think. And why does it snap correctly from one side but not from the other side. Really strange if you ask me.