# Merging polygons of single feature using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I am new to QGIS and have done some research on this topic before posting but not sure I found an answer.

I have one feature that has multiple polygons (islands of a nation). In reality, there is only one island, but my file has split the island into two polygons. I have turned on editing mode and selected the nodes of the one island and moved the polygon so it is adjacent to the other polygon, but now I have a line down the middle.

Is there a way either merge the polygon into one, or remove the line down the middle or some other way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Welcome at StackExchange GIS! Have you tried to dissolve your polygons based upon that feature? Menu Vector->Geoprocessing Tools ->Dissolve

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132847/merge-two-points-of-two-different-polygons-to-get-one-polygon-at-the-end/132850#132850) would do it.

Comment: You could also look into **Multiparts to singleparts** (_Vector_ > _Geometry Tools_ > _Multiparts to singleparts_)