# How to fill the empty space automatically, QGIS 2.16.3

Tags: qgis, polygon, depression-filling

Is it possible to fill empty space inside of polygon?
I have problem, a clever boy drilled my polygons with road polygon,and I want to fill up polygons again, but how? I cannot merge every single polygon by hand, it would be too much. Different color means different polygon with attribute data.Thanks
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In FME I would snap area's to area's goup by id and then dissolve. 5 minute job as long as roads are not clipped on borders. Not sure how to do this in QGIS but should be possible.

Comment: I don't have a unique field for polygons.  Area merged with dash dash lines is main area and those polygons splitted into smaller polygons.The roads splitted polygons, but the same attribute data. This is an area with a different type of forest. I will try to make unique field.

Comment: you can try using GRASS v.clean snap.

Comment: I did not succeed in any case. The problem is that, when I fill the road empty space, that empty space has no data. So it can not dissolve polygons. I think there is no solution in this case.

Comment: I can just remember trying: remove all roads, buffer of average size of roads, dissolve by attributes, buffer the inverse average size of the roads. Although This will lead to small gaps between some borders... But maybe that is less to fix than all roads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no data, but here is the solution to your problem: 1) Create an external boundary polygon that covers all your data and cut it with your original polygons - the result is your road type - polygon; 2) Polygons to points, then pass polygon attributes to road lines, and from lines with the same attributes, create roads to subpoles; 3) Dissolve the sub-polygons of the road by attributes, i.e. if the sub-polygon concerns polygons whose id is the same, then such polygons combined...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132847/merge-two-points-of-two-different-polygons-to-get-one-polygon-at-the-end