# Merging island into simplified polygon

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, qgis-2

I have a polygon shapefile with holes (representing Islands and Rivers) within it as seen below:

[image]

I need an automated way to fill the polygon in QGIS as seen below: That is remove all Islands and divisions within and outside the polygon.

[image]

I know I can creating a separate layer and manually digitize the area, but there are many of such polygons.

I tried the following, non worked:

1- Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singlepart

2- Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve

3- Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Eliminate Silver Polygons

**Graphic/image explanation above:**
What I have is the first image, but what I want is the second image.

**Edited:**
The answer here [How to smooth/generalize a polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis) over generalized the boundaries into straight line (polygon shape deformed) and it does it for separate Island. What I wanted is to eliminate the gaps (Islands) in between and keep the bigger polygon retaining the shape as close as possible.

The shapefile of the image above is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wmhfkii8eosykl/polygon-to-gen.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What determines where the "short-cut" should go. For example, why leave the small islands on the left side and cut off the parts at the bottom? Alternatively, why did you draw the line at the bottom where you did (as opposed to higher or lower in Y direction)? If you want an automated approach, you need an objective measure / condition. What is that condition?

Comment: Pardon my graphics edit am not good with photoshop. My objective measure is simply to have a solid filled polygon nothing more than that.

Comment: The easiest algorithm that will solidify the polygon to resemble the original will be OK, details lose isn't of much concern here. Thanks

Comment: How about a convex hull?

Comment: @BradHards or better still, a concave hull - see my answer

Comment: You don't want to remove the island, you want to simply the islands into the polygon.

Answer (score 7):

A *simplification* operation should get rid of most of the crinkly bits, but wont join islands to the mainland, and might lose detail at the top of your mainland in this example. You need to set a tolerance for the simplification.

To join everything into one big blob I can think of two possibilities:

First, do a buffering operation so that all the things you want to overlap now overlap, so you'll have to choose a buffer width carefully. Then merge all the polygons, and because they overlap you'll get one feature. Then do a *negative* buffer of the same size to get back to roughly where you started. There will be some detail loss in places.

Alternatively, look at computing a "concave hull", or *alpha shape* polygon of your feature. There's some QGIS code here:

https://github.com/detlevn/QGIS-ConcaveHull-Plugin

This plugin **is** in the QGIS plugin repo.

Concave hulls still need to be given a tuning parameter so you may be disappointed with the result, but that's just how the mathematics works out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with the roads,[How to fill the empty space automatically, QGIS 2.16.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214502/how-to-fill-the-empty-space-automatically-qgis-2-16-3). You can try to make model like I am. Create your distance buffer + and create buffer - . Maybe this helps you.
[image]

Comment: +1 The buffer -buffer method works well for these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround could solve your problem (don't worry about the length of the answer because it's a really simple procedure).

You only need to convert your polygon to lines and then doing the opposite (you just have to pay "attention" to select a specific output as you will see later).

I'll explain my idea with this sample shapefile (it seems similar to yours):

[image]

Firstly, convert the polygon to lines using the **Polygons to lines** tool from `Vector` > `Geometry Tools` (or from the **Processing Toolbox**):

[image]

Then, convert this output to polygons using the **Lines to polygons** tool from `Vector` > `Geometry Tools` (or from the **Processing Toolbox**):

[image]

Once you have done this, you only have to select the area of interest, which is in general the largest one (it's rare the selection of more than one feature but, however, adapt the selection to your specific case):

[image]

Save the selected features/s with the **Save selected features** tool from the **Processing Toolbox** and you will obtain this:

[image]

Finally, this is the overlap of the input file on the output of the last saving operation:

[image]

A quick comment: this procedure doesn't apply any simplification, so you won't loss the original level of detail.

Comment: This sounds interesting, let me give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately my final result still had openings (holes) in between the larger polygon after following your guide. My shapefile at: dropbox.com/s/0wmhfkii8eosykl/polygon-to-gen.zip?dl=0

Comment: The guide spitted or explored the polygons but not fill it to form a solid polygon.

Comment: Do you satisfied with any answer?